# How to exclude the lib folder in maven?

Tags: java, maven

How can I exclude the `lib` folder using maven? I don't want these resources to be copied when packaging and building war file.

The following does not work:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/**</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Example path:

```
../lib/my/path/to/lib.jar
```

Running `mvn package` will include all files from the lib folder.

Comment: Simply don't put something into it, cause it's not needed. Use dependencies etc.

Comment: The lib folder contains a local dependency that I inluded in maven config. I do not want to install that dependency to local repo.

Comment: I didn't talked about a local repo. I would suggest to use a repository manager where such artifacts belong to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following from [Creating Skinny WARs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html):

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- In version 2.1-alpha-1, this was incorrectly named warSourceExcludes -->
          <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could mark that dependency as `<scope>provided</scope>` and keep it in a localrepo in your source tree instead of the `lib` folder

Cheers,

Comment: Installing in the local folder would still be a better option compared to `provided` scope